# Good module for Item Response Theory (IRT) in python

Tags: python, r

I'm working on a project related to IRT.

I really want to analyze my data with python.
I googled it, but I couldn't find the module I need.

Do you know some great modules that can handle IRT?

Here is the list of what I want to do:

1. estimation of the graded response model (GRM)
2. equating using the GRM
3. estimation of the multi-dimensional GRM
4. equation using the multi-dimensional GRM

If there is no module in python, I also want to know the packages of R, STAN, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any python module.

The most flexible and competitive IRT packages in R are maybe [mirt](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=mirt) and [TAM](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TAM). See also the [CRAN TASK VIEW on Psychometrics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html)